# Signature with document locking gets invalid in case of PAdES part 4

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7

I am facing an issue in which I have set document locking functionality in case of PAdES part 4. The signature gets invalid after performing document time stamp signature.

Code snippet of document locking functionality is as follows:

```
PdfSigFieldLock pdfSigFieldLock = new PdfSigFieldLock();
pdfSigFieldLock.SetDocumentPermissions(PdfSigFieldLock.LockPermissions.NO_CHANGES_ALLOWED);
string[] fieldToLock = new string[] { signingRequest.FieldName };
pdfSigFieldLock.SetFieldLock(PdfSigFieldLock.LockAction.ALL, fieldToLock);
pdfSigFieldLock.GetPdfObject().Remove(PdfName.Fields);
pdfSigner.SetFieldLockDict(pdfSigFieldLock);
```

The document is attached here:
https://ascertia0-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/muddassir_awan_ascertia_com/EpCcxOWGtLdIlR7MYO9LXf0BNtrUim3aCFdCUNbeRK8rIw?e=xAGnMU

Regards,
Muddassir Awan

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug in Adobe Acrobat signature validation routines; Adobe *PDF Architect & Principal Scientist* Leonard Rosenthol promised to *address it in a future release*.

See [this comment](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3017?focusedCommentId=17224930&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-17224930) to Apache PDFBox issue PDFBOX-3017:

| Maruan Sahyoun added a comment - 02/Nov/20 20:14 |
| --- |

> Got an update from Leonard Rosenthol:
>
> > Wanted to get back to you that we have logged a bug around this and will address it in a future release.
> >
> > Thanks for calling this to our attention.
>
> Further
>
> > Me: For my understanding - it's correct that adding LTV after signing should be possible but currently wrongly flagged by Acrobat?
> >
> > Leonard: Correct

One minute issue, though: You added an extension entry:

```
/Extensions<</ESIC<</BaseVersion/1.7/ExtensionLevel 5>>>>
```

While this indeed *could be a great hint* to validators that PAdES syntax is used, it *strictly speaking is invalid* in your PDF which declares itself as PDF-1.6, see the discussion in [this eSig DSS issue](https://ec.europa.eu/cefdigital/tracker/browse/DSS-2392).

Comment: Thank you for the response on it.
So as a workaround If I remove the extension entry, It should be validated then?
Regards,
Muddassir Awan

Comment: *"So as a workaround If I remove the extension entry, It should be validated then?"* - No, it's just a minute issue I saw in your document, not the main issue which is an error in Adobe Acrobat.