# Setting MD 1 with PDFBOX invalidates the Certificate

Tags: java, pdfbox, digital-signature

Using PDFBOX for document Certification
With AddValidationInformation and

```
 if (accessPermissions == 0)
    {
        SigUtils.setMDPPermission(document, signature, 1);
    }
```

*accessPermissions =1 (No changes to the document are permitted)*

**Certification gets invalidated.**

Along with validateSignature() for LTV

```
 try (ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream())
    {
        this.signDetached(signatureInterface,document,byteArrayOutputStream);
        
        Path tempFilePath=this.resize(path);
        Files.write(tempFilePath,byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());


        AddValidationInformation addOcspInformation = new AddValidationInformation();
        File inFile = new File(tempFilePath.toUri());
        File outFile = new File(path.toUri());

        addOcspInformation.validateSignature(inFile, outFile);

        Files.write(path,byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());

    }
```

With AddValidationInformation class same as
https://github.com/apache/pdfbox/blob/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/signature/validation/AddValidationInformation.java

PDFBOX version : 2.0.24

Thanks in advance.
Cheers!!!

Note: If available, adobe bug Id would be helpful.

Comment: *"Using PDFBOX for document Certification With AddValidationInformation"* is a bit vague. Do you by chance mean that after adding a certification signature with *no-changes-permitted* (1) you add validation related information in  an incremental update? In that case you're running into a well-known bug of Adobe Acrobat. Otherwise please explain more exactly.

Comment: yes, I mean adding certification signature with no-changes-permitted.

Comment: *"yes, I mean adding certification signature with no-changes-permitted."* - ... and you also *add validation related information in an incremental update*?

Comment: Yes, for LTV. I updated my question with snippet.  signatureInterface implementation is similar to pdfbox example on github. thanks much for  helping me out.

Comment: The PDFBox issue comment referenced from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66422552/1729265) is currently all we have, just Leonard writing that they at Adobe *logged a bug around this and will address it in a future release*.

Comment: Thank you. This helps

Comment: Ok. I'll mark your question as a duplicate of that question, ok?

Comment: Yes, that will do